# Use a CSS Attribute selector to style a checked check box. (Android GMAIL)

Tags: css, html-email, android-checkbox

I am working an an email template and I am trying to use a checkbox to display additional information when the box is checked (for android Gmail client). I currently have a working setup that uses a button with focus to change the display of the content to inline. Once the user clicks the focus off the button the additional information goes back to display:none.

Sample Code of button Configuration

```
    button.showDetails:focus + .moreInfo {display:inline!important;} //Toggles content on when focused to display moreInfo.
```

```
<button type="button" class ="showDetails" style ="//display:none;   /* background:whitesmoke; outline:none; border:none; width:0px; height:0px;*/">Leasing Terms</button> <!!--Hide Button for GMAIL by styling CSS. Reveal in others with body CSS.-->

<table  class ="moreInfo"  width="240px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style ="display:none;">
    <tr>
       <td width="50%" align="center" style="font-size:.7em;">$269 a month lease for 36 months. 12,000 miles per year. $2,000 due at signing and no security deposit required. On approved credit. An extra charge may be imposed at the end of the lease term due to mileage overage. Price plus tax, title, and license.</td>
    </tr>                                                        
</table>
```

According to campaign monitor https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ Android GMAIL does not support the :focus pseudo-selector.  As a work around for android GMAIL I am trying to use a checkbox and use a combination of the attribute selector and general sibling selector. Is it possible to use an attribute selector to style a checkbox or in this case the sibling of that checkbox if the checkbox is checked?

Here is the example for checkbox.

```
<style>
    input.showDetails[checked = "checked"] ~ .moreInfo  {-webkit-display:inline!important;}
</style> 
<input class= "showDetails" type="checkbox" >Disclaimer
                        <button type="button" class ="showDetails" style =" width:100%;display:none;   /* background:whitesmoke; outline:none; border:none; width:0px; height:0px;*/">New Vehicles Disclaimer</button> <!!--Hide Button for GMAIL by styling CSS. Reveal in others with body CSS.-->    
                        <p class="moreInfo" style="display:none">All prices plus tax, title, license, and doc fee. See dealer for details</p>
```

I did get the attribute selector and sibling selector to work when I placed the style tag at the bottom of the body tag, but only when the checkbox's default was set to checked. Anyway to use css to style a checkbox once it has been checked by the user? Any other methods that might have a similar effect?

Thanks

P.s. javascript and jquery cannot be used.

Comment: Can you add any value to your checkbox ?

Comment: Have you tried the `:checked` pseudo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I came up with to display additional content on focus without using a button or other input forms, and no javascript. It works fine enough. I did not find any solution other than just displaying all the information for android gmail. I used tabindex attribute on the span tag so it will get focus similar to an input element.

```
/*Toggles content on when focused to display moreInfo.*/ 
.showDetails:focus + table.moreInfo {
            display:inline!important;
 } 

 .buttonStyle:hover {
        background-color: #215ace;
        cursor: pointer;
  }



<span tabindex="50" class="showDetails displayButton" style="outline:none; //display:none;" >
      <table class="buttonStyle" width="80%" height="20px" bgcolor="#022b7f" style ="background-image: url(Links/Highlight-Button.png); background-repeat:repeat-x; color:#ffffff; border-radius:10px; border-style:outset; border-width:1px; border-color:navy;">
             <tr>
                 <td align="center"><span>New Vehicle Disclaimer</span></td>
             </tr>
      </table>
</span>
<table class="moreInfo" width="100%" bgcolor="lightblue" style="display:none;">
        <tr>
            <td>All prices plus tax, title, license, and doc fee. See dealer for details</td>
        </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the checkbox is checked , you can do this

```
.showDetails:checked {
    margin-top:2%;
}
```

Comment: :checked pseudo selector works for a traditional website, but I don't believe it is a supported selector for most, if any email clients. I was hoping there was an attribute for a checkbox that would recognize whenever a box is checked using a simple attribute selector. It appears this particular attribute selector only works once when the html is fully loaded, not after a user interaction takes place.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `checked` *attribute* of the checkbox corresponds to its `defaultChecked` DOM property, not `checked`, and doesn't reflect the change of the `checked` state. So `[checked = "checked"]` in CSS shouldn't reflect it, too, and has different meaning than `:checked` pseudo selector.

You can try to use something like

> input.showDetails:not(:checked) ~ .moreInfo  {display:none;}

that will hide the details in mail programs that support both `:not()` and `:checked` selectors (according to campaign monitor, Android 4 Gmail supports at least the first one), falling back to always visible details in programs that don't support any of them.

Alternatively, you can try HTML5 `detail` element, which has [rather good support](http://caniuse.com/#search=details) in WebKit-based products (I'd expect that products based on Android Web component should support it).

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I will give that a shot as soon as I can. I did find an interesting "hack" or alternate use for a checkbox that may work.  http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/ It requires a label tag and using that sort of like a button. But then my big question is do they support the label tags? I might just scrap my button idea as well. I don't believe that is supported either. I need to convince my employer for an email testing subscription with litmus.

Comment: This "hack" is still based on `:checked` pseudo class, so it won't work if `:checked` not supported(

Comment: I am working on a solution to use a table wrapped in a span tag instead of using a button. Then for the android gmail client I am going to try and use the :visited pseudo selector on a link (html markup that I will hide from everything but the gmail.) I have tried this before with the links and it works only that one time to display the content, however once it is clicked the info will not be able to toggle like the button using the :focus selector. All else fails they just see everything from the get go. I will posted this as my answer if it works well enough.

Comment: u are wrong :checked corresponds to current state, its updated dynamically

Comment: @Prozi, `:checked` _pseudo class_ corresponds to current state, but `[checked]` _attribute_ (as in the question) _doesn't_. The whole problem was in confusion between these.